# Is it possible to view secret variable declared in angular in browser, after build and run?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use an a decryption algorithm on the data I receive through REST-API, for that I am storing the secret-key in angular component ts file.

I want to know that after I build and deploy the code. Will my secret key be visible somewhere in the browser, because the built code is pure javascript which is fetched by server.

I am using crypto-js library for decryption of data.

```
var secret_key = "super-secret";

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, secret_key)
```

Comment: Anything in the browser is considered compromised. Do not do this.

Comment: If you write code in javascript, that code is delivered to the web browser of whoever runs it.  If your secret key is a string, it will be plainly visible in the source code.

Comment: I would suggest put secret key inside .env file not even in normal .js file on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can explain the situation why you need it, may be a chance you can get better way to do it.

There are 3 different ways to achieve it :-

1. Pass roles/permissions to local storage as well as same time put into session table(or any other table) in backend. Check role/permission every time user request for something to make sure it is not modified.
2. Store the roles/permission in backend e.g in session table and then provide roles/permission on every request. This way you do not have to worry about any modification by user anytime.
3. Pass the encrypted (RSA algorithm)roles/permission in cookies and make cookie httpOnly true and secure true, these cookies cannot be accessed/modified as per protocol and then in each request you will have

Comment: I want to encrypt localStorage Data, so that the user can't modify it. Later I am using localstorage data after decryption for all other operations such as access control and permissions.

Comment: The user will always be able to modify localStorage data.  Encryption will not solve that problem.

Comment: but the decryption will not work on modified localstorage data

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be visible to individuals looking for it.  You should never store secrets in any client-side code.

The key should be acquired from a server once the client authenticates.

Good post on key storage options
https://pomcor.com/2017/06/02/keys-in-browser/

Section 5.2 of WebCryptoAPI discusses a bit about key storage

https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to execute encrypt/decrypt operation on backend (server-side) and get the decrypted value from you API